# How can I manage trolls and griefers?

Tags: left-4-dead-2

Trolls and griefers are common in multiplayer, potentially because the game is *significantly* discounted during Steam sales and has been given away at least once [in 2013](http://store.steampowered.com/news/12151/). Approximately 50% of the full games I play there's one or more players who consistently do damage to team players and waste items. How can I avoid playing with such people?

Comment: There really isn't much you can do unless you own a server or there are proper reporting tools in place. This is a primarily opinion based question otherwise, and I'm voting to close as such.

Comment: Vote kick them. Steam report them. Switch servers. Not fun when they show up, I agree, but not a lot of options unless you want to run custom servers. I spend about half my play time finding a server/team that isn't newbs or griefers. But once I find a good group, man, is this game fun!

Comment: I agree with @Kaizerwolf that there is not much you can do, except to quit the server. That's the reason I quit playing this game altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest hosting your own server (*extremely* simple and can be done directly in the game) for total control. Install [Admin System](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=214630948) mod from Steam Workshop (and [Admin Menu](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=574484797) if you want GUI). The commands are executed in the game chat. For example, `!ban Bill` permanently bans the player who is playing as Bill by adding his unique Steam profile ID to the blacklist. `!kick Bill` would kick the player, but please note that he can rejoin the server.

View all available commands here: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=213591107

[image]

Comment: So this is basically a plug for some Steam admin tool? Telling a user "host your own server" isn't a good solution at all...

Comment: @Kaizerwolf: It's not a "Steam admin tool". It's a mod that enables commands and provides easy access to them. Hosting own server is easy in L4D2 and can be done directly from the game menu.("create a new lobby").   
I feel that you may have misunderstood and I ask you to remove your potential downvotes from both of my question and answer.

Comment: Either way, it looks like you're plugging this workshop item. If the whole reason for asking this was to plug this, you're perilously close to the spam line.

Comment: @Frank: Workshop mods can't be (easily) monetized and I'm not related to the mod in any way. Please answer the question if you know a more effective way to ban and penalize.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Did you ask this only to plug this mod?

Comment: @Frank: Certainly not.